# Remove GridView Column using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

i m using grid view in my web application with auto generated column is false and bind this grid with data table. now i want to generated excel file to this grid view with selected column and give to functionality to user  choose selected columns at run times with check box so can any one help me to bind grid view columns header with check box in java script or any other way to do this.

Comment: Can you please provide a piece of html markup(http://jsfiddle.net/). Things will go faster this way.

Comment: see this post it will helpful to you

http://manish4dotnet.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-bind-data-to-gridview-using.html